# QT Central Widget doesn't appear

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a problem with setCentralWidget() displaying.
Here is constructor of main window:

```
MW_MusicRenamerApp::MW_MusicRenamerApp(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MW_MusicRenamerApp)
{
    //setup main window settings
    //using functions for setup, set and change parts of main window
    addToolBar(Qt::RightToolBarArea, createRightToolBar());
    setCentralWidget(createCentralWidget());

    ui->setupUi(this);//for the moment of writing IDK what it's, so don't delete
}
```

Here is central widget creation:

```
QWidget *MW_MusicRenamerApp::createCentralWidget()
{
    QWidget *centralWgt = new QWidget(); //this one will be returned

    //creating left part of the central widget
    QStringListModel *strlm_fileNames = new QStringListModel(m_strl_fileNames_temp, 0);
    QListView *lv_fileNames = new QListView();
    lv_fileNames->setModel(strlm_fileNames);
    //creating right part of central widget
    QStringListModel *strlm_temp = new  QStringListModel(m_strl_fileNames_temp, 0);
    QListView *lv_renamingResult = new QListView();
    lv_renamingResult->setModel(strlm_temp);

    //layout setup
    QHBoxLayout *hbxl_centralWgtLayout = new QHBoxLayout();
    hbxl_centralWgtLayout->addWidget(lv_fileNames);
    hbxl_centralWgtLayout->addWidget(lv_renamingResult);

    centralWgt->setLayout(hbxl_centralWgtLayout);
    centralWgt->show(); //do i realy need this?

    return centralWgt;
}
```

So, when I run my program, the central widget doesn't appear, even if I try to set QPushButton as a central widget, like this:

```
QPushButton *temp_btn = new QPushButton("ONE BIG BUTTON");
setCentralWidget(temp_btn):
```

or like this:

```
setCentralWidget(new QPushButton("ONE BIG BUTTON"));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: move `ui->setupUi(this);` before `setCentralWidget`

Comment: Thanks a lot, its works. Can i delete any references on ui-like things in my code?

Comment: If you are not going to use the .ui then remove all its reference